# rewrite rules for nginx and Codeigniter

Tags: nginx, codeigniter-3, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have implemented a php application in codeigniter and now want to deploy it to the nginx server. Before deploying I checked my nignx configuration on my localhost using MAMP server. It is working correctly. But, this configuration is not working on the live server. As a beginner in nginx, I am not understanding where is the mistake here. In live server, I can not write in the main nginx.conf file. I have a separate configuration file like "abc" for my application "abc". And all my application files are under "abc/xyz" directory. Here is my sample confuguration,

```
location /abc {
root /srv/www/htdocs/apps/;

index index.html index.htm index.php;


location /xyz {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /abc/xyz/index.php;
}

location ~ \.php(\/(\w+))*$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    rewrite (.+)\.php(\/(\w+))*$ $1.php break;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

}

Here, I can see my welcome page https://myapplication/abc/xyz. But if I want to navigate other pages like https://myapplication/abc/xyz/other_pages, it is showing "404 Page not found". I have checked the other solutions but none of them is not working in this case. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. It was actually very silly mistake. My controller page name was in small character. This is why it was not working. My configuration is okay. The first letter of the controller page should be in capital character. For example, my controller name is Home. So my php file name must be Home.php not home.php.

Answer (score 0):

The `location /xyz` block is nested within the `location /abc` block. The nested block is required to precess URIs with a prefix of `/abc/xyz`.

If there are other *regular expression* `location` blocks surrounding your `location /abc` block`, you should use the`^~` modifier.

For example:

```
location ^~ /abc {
    ...
    location /abc/xyz {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.